# Error for create_slope_cs function in the leastcostpath package

Tags: r, raster

guys! I encountered an error when creating a cost surface based on DEM data.

```
Adm1 <-
    rgeoboundaries::geoboundaries(
      country = "Austria",
      adm_lvl = "adm0")
r <- get_elev_raster(Adm1,z=4)
cs <- create_slope_cs(dem = r, cost_function = 'tobler', neighbours = 16)
```

The error is like

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :

error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extent': ‘srs’ is not a slot in class “BasicRaster”
```

I can run this code on my other laptop. So I think there's nothing wrong with my code. But do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this for sure, but I suspect the issue might have originated in the terra package, which the raster package uses internally. Try updating both the raster and terra packages.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SpatRaster (from terra) where the function expects a RasterLayer (from raster)

This ought to work

```
library(raster)
x <- raster(r)
cs <- create_slope_cs(dem = x, cost_function = 'tobler', neighbours = 16)
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by updating all my packages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).